# Para que serve Handled nos argumentos C#

Tags: c#

Eu vi em alguns códigos o uso do Handled sendo atribuido como true e false dos argumentos de eventos de ComboBox - SelectionChanged, TextBox - LostFocus, Button - Click.

Gostaria de saber para que serve e o que ele modifica no evento ou no controle?

Exemplo

```
    private void cboNome_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {          
        e.Handled = true; 
    }
```

Comment: De uma olhada no site da ms:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Pelo o que eu entendi ele serve tipo como se fosse para cancelar a ação do evento, ou melhor para não alterar o controle q disparou o evento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definição de Handled segundo o site da microsoft:

> Obtém ou define um valor que indica se o evento foi tratado.

Exemplo do uso do controle handled.

(Irá  determinar se o usuário pressionou uma tecla não-numérica no textbox e em caso afirmativo, cancela o evento KeyPress usando a propriedade Handled)

```
 //Sinalizador booleano usado para determinar quando uma tecla  não numérica  é digitada.
    private bool nonNumberEntered = false;

    // Manipula o evento KeyDown para determinar o tipo de caractere digitado no controle.
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Inicializa a flag com false
        nonNumberEntered = false;

        //Determina se o numero pressionado é do conjunto superior do teclado
        if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9)
        {
            // Determina se o numero pressionado é do keypad.
            if (e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9)
            {
                // Determina se a tecla pressionada é backspace
                if(e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
                {
                    // Um numero não numérico foi pressionado
                    // Seta a flag como true.
                    nonNumberEntered = true;
                }
            }
        }
        //Verifica se a tecla pressiona é shift
        if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift) {
            nonNumberEntered = true;
        }
    }

 //Esse evento previne que caracteres digitados apos o evento KeyDown afetem o controle
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
       // Verifca a flag que esta sendo definida no evento do KeyDown
        if (nonNumberEntered == true)
        {
            // Previne que caracteres não numéricos entrem no controle
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Para mais detalhes, veja

-> https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrippanelrendereventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx

-> https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

-> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/pt-BR?query=Handled&emptyWatermark=true&ac=4