# Como consigo detectar se o valor de um textbox tem letras?

Tags: c#

Como é possível validar num `TextBox` quando o usuário digitar letras ao invés de números aparecer um aviso:

> só é permitido digitar números neste campo

Com qual função posso verificar?

Comment: Web ou Desktop?

Comment: Uma função Javascript te ajudaria?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utlizar o código

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = !((e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9) || (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) ||
        (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab || e.KeyCode == Keys.Back || e.KeyCode == Keys.Capital || e.KeyCode == Keys.CapsLock || e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter ||
        e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert || e.KeyCode == Keys.Home || e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete || e.KeyCode == Keys.End || (e.KeyCode >= Keys.Left && e.KeyCode <= Keys.Down)));

    if (e.SuppressKeyPress)
        MessageBox.Show("só é permitido digitar números neste campo");

}
```

Neste código, tudo o que **não** for número e teclas especiais de navegação e edição eu seto a propriedade `SuppressKeyPress` com `true` para suprimir a tecla precionada.

Answer (score 1):

### Uma solução muito simples - WinForms

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != ',')) {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    if (e.Handled)
        MessageBox.Show("Só é permitido digitar números neste campo");
}
```

Observe que acrescentei na condição para permitir também o nosso separador decimal ´,´. Se você quer permitir apenas números, basta retirar a última condição.

```
if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) {
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Referências:

1. [Para que serve Handled nos argumentos C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57502/para-que-serve-handled-nos-argumentos-c)
2. [Propriedade KeyPressEventArgs.Handled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [Como manipular a entrada do teclado no nível do formulário](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms171538(v=vs.110).aspx)

### Solução para ASP.Net

Adicione em sua página um [`CompareValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw(v=vs.85).aspx) e utilize a propriedade `DataTypeCheck` e no `Type` defina como quiser:

```
...
Type="String|Integer|Double|Date|Currency"
...

<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" 
 ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Só é permitido digitar números neste campo"/>
```